# How to interpret a break in linearity when performing detrended fluctuation analysis?

Tags: time-frequency, time-series, scaling

I have time series with 1048 values and when I perform detrended fluctuation analysis on this time series (using the windows or scales of `2^4` to `2^10` values) to calculate the alpha-component I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the relation is linear with `alpha 1.53` indicating a non-stationary process. However, there's a break in the linearity approximately at `2^7` to `2^8` which translates to the windows of `128` to `256` values. Then it gets into the previous pattern more or less.

**How can I interpreret this break?**

My idea is that we could say that on the windows from 16 to 128 values, there is a power-law relation between the sum of the fluctuations and the window size and the bigger is the scale, the (much) more likely we are to see big fluctuations.

However, at the windows between 128 and 256 values we some some anomalities emerging, which then subside at the windows of 256 values and higher.

Could we say that there is a certain "critical" area in this time series in scales between `128` and `256` size where we are likely to see highly unexpected events?

Do you have any other ideas how we could interpret this?

Comment: I'm guessing it's an artifact your window size approaching your data size (which doesn't make much sense), but it's hard to tell without looking at the details for your specific analysis procedure.

Comment: If that was an artefact, it could have appeared for the bigger window sizes. The data size does make sense for DFA — if you review the literature on using this method for estimating the variability of a gait, for example, there are even less values there. The specific analysis procedure I use is the DFA algorithm. Detrend, get the sum of the fluctuations from the mean, calculate for the different time windows.